# moving data from one database table to another after a certain period of time

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a database table which contains various details about users. Eventually their will be many thousands of users so I want to move 'inactive' users from a current table to an archive table (therefore preserving all their settings in case they return to the site, but doesnt 'clog up' the main user table and its queries). Id want users that hadnt logged in for a month to be moved from the main to the archive table. I already keep a time stamp of when the user last logged in stored in the database so implementing the code to move from one table to another will be fairly easy.

My question is how to implement this automatically. I obviously dont want it coded into a webpage that is accessed by users as this would make it run far too often, but I also dont want the code to have to be run manually. Is there a function in PHP which will run every [day/week/etc] at a specific time - and then run an SQL query from there to move the inactive members?

Comment: Do you have access to the cron jobs on the server?  That'd be the simplest way to set it up.  If not you could always build a password protected page that only you could access to run it.

Comment: just how many archival users are you talking about? a proper DB engine shouldn't have any trouble with thousands/tens-of-thousands of records.

Comment: With the right indices and something like an `active` column, I doubt you will find any difference with the inactive users in the table or in another one.

Comment: Well, the client is expecting 1000+ sign ups per month in the long term, and wants to keep their details for at least a year, but due to the nature of the website only a months worth of users want to be in the main database table at any time (their details are searchable by "super users" so only current users are required)

Comment: doesn't sound like you really need to move them, those numbers are low

Comment: @jeroen that's good to know, although I think I will look more into this cron option aswell because in 12 months time I will hit the same problem but with needing to remove their details completely rather than marking them inactive. Also how would the 'active' column be updated automatically after a month without the user logging in to affect that users data row?

Comment: you don't need an 'active' column, just a last logged in one (timestamp).

Comment: @Giovanni You are definitely going to need cron jobs :-)

Comment: @dagon, ha I thought it was an ambitious amount of users to be honest :) but in any case what are your thoughts on my previous comment about marking the column 'inactive' automatically?

Comment: @Dagon True, I have more use-cases for an `active` column so I didn't really think about it but here it is not needed.

Comment: @dagon excellent point. Mustve been looking at this too long to not think of that!

Comment: don't bother, just use a date, 'active' is business logic, today its 1 month, next week its 6 months, if you just use the date, its easy to manage in a querry

Comment: I think what Dagon meant is that you wouldn't need to mark them as inactive per se, you could just only select from the pool of users that are active within the last few months.  Effectively ignoring the rest.

Comment: just dont forget to index the date field.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add your PHP script that is performing this task to your server's CRON. You can configure it in your server settings.